# What Windows app source artifacts should be excluded from public source control?

Tags: windows-8, version-control, open-source, windows-store-apps, windows-store

I'm building a Windows 8/8.1 app and would like to upload it to GitHub to share out and accept community contributions. Which project artifacts are linked to my developer account and should be excluded from posting publicly?

Some files I see in the project:

```
*.cs
*.xaml
*.xaml.cs
*.csproj
*_StoreKey.pfx
*_TemporaryKey.pfx
Package.appxmanifest
Package.StoreAssociation.xml
```

Comment: I think you must exclude (*.suo , *.csproj.user , 'bin' folder , 'obj' folder).., not sure, may be.

Comment: @houssam: Yes, those are build artifacts and will need to be excluded.  Windows Store apps are linked to a developer account, so I want to ensure I don't leak any sensitive metadata stored about my account.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally you can exclude `*.pfx` files, because they are certificates. `Package.StoreAssociation` is also useless, without certificates.

Additionally, there are `.gitignore` file created by Visual Studio 2013, it can be useful to exclude all non related to the sources stuff:

```
## Ignore Visual Studio temporary files, build results, and
## files generated by popular Visual Studio add-ons.

# User-specific files
*.suo
*.user
*.sln.docstates

# Build results

[Dd]ebug/
[Rr]elease/
x64/
build/
[Bb]in/
[Oo]bj/

# Enable "build/" folder in the NuGet Packages folder since NuGet packages use it for MSBuild targets
!packages/*/build/

# MSTest test Results
[Tt]est[Rr]esult*/
[Bb]uild[Ll]og.*

*_i.c
*_p.c
*.ilk
*.meta
*.obj
*.pch
*.pdb
*.pgc
*.pgd
*.rsp
*.sbr
*.tlb
*.tli
*.tlh
*.tmp
*.tmp_proj
*.log
*.vspscc
*.vssscc
.builds
*.pidb
*.log
*.scc

# Visual C++ cache files
ipch/
*.aps
*.ncb
*.opensdf
*.sdf
*.cachefile

# Visual Studio profiler
*.psess
*.vsp
*.vspx

# Guidance Automation Toolkit
*.gpState

# ReSharper is a .NET coding add-in
_ReSharper*/
*.[Rr]e[Ss]harper

# TeamCity is a build add-in
_TeamCity*

# DotCover is a Code Coverage Tool
*.dotCover

# NCrunch
*.ncrunch*
.*crunch*.local.xml

# Installshield output folder
[Ee]xpress/

# DocProject is a documentation generator add-in
DocProject/buildhelp/
DocProject/Help/*.HxT
DocProject/Help/*.HxC
DocProject/Help/*.hhc
DocProject/Help/*.hhk
DocProject/Help/*.hhp
DocProject/Help/Html2
DocProject/Help/html

# Click-Once directory
publish/

# Publish Web Output
*.Publish.xml

# NuGet Packages Directory
## TODO: If you have NuGet Package Restore enabled, uncomment the next line
#packages/

# Windows Azure Build Output
csx
*.build.csdef

# Windows Store app package directory
AppPackages/

# Others
sql/
*.Cache
ClientBin/
[Ss]tyle[Cc]op.*
~$*
*~
*.dbmdl
*.[Pp]ublish.xml
*.pfx
*.publishsettings

# RIA/Silverlight projects
Generated_Code/

# Backup & report files from converting an old project file to a newer
# Visual Studio version. Backup files are not needed, because we have git ;-)
_UpgradeReport_Files/
Backup*/
UpgradeLog*.XML
UpgradeLog*.htm

# SQL Server files
App_Data/*.mdf
App_Data/*.ldf


#LightSwitch generated files
GeneratedArtifacts/
_Pvt_Extensions/
ModelManifest.xml

# =========================
# Windows detritus
# =========================

# Windows image file caches
Thumbs.db
ehthumbs.db

# Folder config file
Desktop.ini

# Recycle Bin used on file shares
$RECYCLE.BIN/

# Mac desktop service store files
.DS_Store
```

Comment: this answer is not clear...are there any security risks for my developer account if I publish some files? The only files that could contain sensitive data are the ones that are modified after I associate an app with my account: **\*_StoreKey.pfx**, **Package.appxmanifest**, **Package.StoreAssociation.xml**

Comment: see this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922239/can-i-publish-the-storekey-pfx-of-an-uwp-application