# Can I publish the StoreKey.pfx of an UWP application

Tags: windows-store-apps, uwp, windows-store

I have an open source windows store application (UWP). When I associate the application with the store a `Package.StoreAssociation.xml` and a `<AppName>_StoreKey.pfx` is created along with some modifications to my `Package.appxmanifest` (Identity Tag; Name and Publisher Attributes).

- Can I commit that information to a public git repository (the certificate must be in the repository because I want to build the package with AppVeyor)?
- Should I encrypt it?
- Could I revoke the certificate if it leaked?
- Are the changes to appxmanifest sensitive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can I commit that information to a public git repository (the certificate must be in the repository because I want to build the package with AppVeyor)?

For public git repository, the Store key .pfx file should not be committed(Add to .gitignore file). If you want to use the CI system, please create a private repository or append the .pfx file to your cloned project in CI backend.

> Should I encrypt it?

This file has been encrypted and it's for signing your app before submitting to Windows Store, see also [How to create an app package signing certificate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/jj835832(v=vs.85).aspx)

> Could I revoke the certificate if it leaked?

You need to reserved a new app name, see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh454036.aspx#LinkStore)

> Are the changes to appxmanifest sensitive?

Depends on what you have changed, it's very important for Identity and package information in .packagemanifest file. See [App package manifest](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br211474.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

You should not include `<AppName>_StoreKey.pfx` file to your public repo. However you can still use **AppVeyor CI**.

1.Change your `*.csproj` file to include this information.

```
<PropertyGroup Condition="('$(Configuration)' == 'Debug') Or ('$(UseTemporarySignCert)' == 'true')">
    <PackageCertificateKeyFile><AppName>_TemporaryKey.pfx</PackageCertificateKeyFile>
</PropertyGroup>
<PropertyGroup Condition="('$(Configuration)' == 'Release') And ('$(UseTemporarySignCert)' != 'true')">
    <PackageCertificateThumbprint><!-- Your <AppName>_StoreKey.pfx Thumbprint Here --></PackageCertificateThumbprint>
</PropertyGroup>
```

2.Import your `<AppName>_StoreKey.pfx` certificate to: store location - **Current User**, Certificate store - **Personal**

3.Add `UseTemporarySignCert` environment variable with value `true` to your **AppVeyor** project.

As result you will be able to build signed project by your own without `<AppName>_StoreKey.pfx` in release mode and publish then to the store.
And **AppVeyor** will work with `TemporaryKey.pfx`.